# How to get/display item from nested list<list<int>> in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a problem in C# to display one element from nested int list.
When I have a list:

```
List<List<int>> List = new List<List<int>>();
```

and sublists:

```
List<int> SubList = new List<int>();
```

and List is filled by three sublists (SubList) like:

```
List = ((1),(2,3),(4,5,6))
```

how can I display eg. only "1"?
When I'm trying this:

```
this.textBox2.Text = (Convert.ToString(List[0][0]));
```

my textBox2 is empty, but when I'm trying to count List and check how many sublists are in List - it works properly (it shows "3"):

```
this.textBox2.Text = (Convert.ToString(List.Count));
```

but how many element are in eg. 1st sublist doesn't work (displays "0", it should display "1"):

```
this.textBox2.Text = (Convert.ToString(List[0].Count));
```

Thanks for help.

EDIT:
I found that when I'm filling List eg.:

```
SubList.Add(2);
SubList.Add(3);
List.Add(SubList);
SubList.Clear();
```

the problems appear - like, when using the same sublist and clear it clears List too.

How can I use properly only one and the same sublist to fill List?

Comment: Can you show _exactly_ how you're filling the list?  The syntax you show is invalid.

Comment: Sounds like your list is actually empty, if you can't get the first item of the list and the `Count` returns zero.  You *should* get an index out of bounds error when getting the first item, but you must be catching that exception and ignoring it.  Don't do that.  That's a very bad thing to do.

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else in the code. Here's a fiddle showing it working (Similar to the answer already provided): http://dotnetfiddle.net/rnIx1b

Would be helpful to see more relevant code.

Comment: I edited my post, the problem is when I'm using only one sublist to fill List eg. in loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a sublist, adding it to the parent list, *then clearing the sublist*:

```
SubList.Add(2);
SubList.Add(3);
List.Add(SubList);
SubList.Clear();
```

Remember that lists are *references*, meaning the outer list is a list of *references* to the inner lists.  When you clear the inner list, the outer list has a reference to the same inner list, so it is cleared as well (since it's the same instance).

It's analogous to:

- "creating" a paper bag
- putting apples in the paper bag
- putting the paper bag in a box
- Emptying the paper bag.

Just because you put the bag in the box doesn't mean you *cloned* the bag. The bag is emptied whether you're looking at is as a bag or as an item in the box.

I would either:

1. Not clear the sublist *unless you need to*
2. Create different list instances for each sub-list when you add it:

   ```
    List.Add(new List<int>(SubList));  // make a copy
   ```
3. Just use different instances for each sublist:

   ```
    SubList = new List<int>();
   ```

Comment: So the only way is to use `List<int> SubList = new List<int>();` in every start of loop?

Comment: Either that or make a copy of the sublist when you add it - each sublist _will need to be a different reference_

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
List<List<int>> List = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> SubList = new List<int>();


List.Add(new List<int> { 1 });
List.Add(new List<int> { 2, 3 });
List.Add(new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 });

this.textBox2.Text = List[0].Count.ToString();
```

This also Works perfectly to display '5':

```
this.textBox2.Text = List[2][1].ToString();
```

I don't know how you're filling the list.

Comment: He wants read value from middle list, so List[1][0] should return number 2 in your example.

Comment: List[i][j] is the correct way for accessing nested lists

Comment: Of course that is. But it missed in version of this answer before last edit.